# What does the asterisk mean for JSDoc @return {*}

Tags: magento2, javascript, docblock

I want to know what the asterisk means for JSDoc @return {*}

```
    `/**
     * @return {*}
     */

    getData = function () {
        var data = storage.get(cacheKey)();
        if ($.isEmptyObject(data)) {
            data = $.initNamespaceStorage('mage-cache-storage').localStorage.get(cacheKey);

            if ($.isEmptyObject(data)) {
                data = initData();
                saveData(data);
            }
        }

        return data;
    };
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The * means ANY type.

```
  /**
 * @return {*(Any-Type)}
 */
```

[jsdoc source](https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html)